# JS + html drop down calculator reset value problem

Tags: javascript, html

everyone! Starting to learn javascript and html, trying to create simple calculator program with two input fields for numbers, operation selection dropdown menu and field with result.

Program computes everything correctly, but it ?resets? result input value to empty string(because ot logs correct value). I already have tried to set innerHTML, innerText and textContent to same thing as value, also did not work.....

Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> JS Calc </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form style="Border: 2px Blue Solid; padding: 2px; background-color: blueviolet;"
        action="eval.html"
        method="get">
    <script>
      function Calculate()
      {
        var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
        var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
        var op = document.getElementById('op').value;
        if (typeof n1 == "undefined" || typeof n2 == "undefined" || typeof op == "undefined")
          return;
        eval('var r =' + n1 + op + n2);
        console.log(r);
        document.getElementById('res').value = r;
      }
    </script>

    <input type="number" id="n1" name="N1" value="1" step="0.001" />
    <select id="op" onchange="Calculate()">
      <option value="+" selected>+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" id="n2" name="N2" value="2" step="0.001" />
    <input type="submit" id="eq" name="Eq" value="=" onclick="Calculate()" />
    <input type="number" id="res" name="Res" step="0.001" disabled />

  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to not `action="..."`. That refreshes the page and updates the GET query string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS Calc</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form
      style="border: 2px Blue Solid; padding: 2px; background-color: blueviolet"
      action="javascript:void(0);"
      method="get"
    >
      <script>
        function Calculate() {
          var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
          var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
          var op = document.getElementById("op").value;
          if (
            typeof n1 == "undefined" ||
            typeof n2 == "undefined" ||
            typeof op == "undefined"
          )
            return;
          eval("var r =" + n1 + op + n2);
          console.log(r);
          document.getElementById("res").value = r;
        }
      </script>

      <input type="number" id="n1" name="N1" value="1" step="0.001" />
      <select id="op" onchange="Calculate()">
        <option value="+" selected>+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
      </select>
      <input type="number" id="n2" name="N2" value="2" step="0.001" />
      <input type="submit" id="eq" name="Eq" value="=" onclick="Calculate()" />
      <input type="number" id="res" name="Res" step="0.001" disabled />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```